# onReceivedSslError() is getting invoked for trusted urls on some devices

Tags: android, ssl, android-webview, webviewclient

My application has a WebView which loads a https url. I have set a WebViewClient to handle ssl error. The problem is, onReceivedSslError() callback is invoked for valid trusted urls on some devices. It's not happening on all devices. Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the reason why some devices get the onReceivedSslError callback is because they have a version of the Android System WebView App that has a bug. See this link:

https://www.chromium.org/developers/androidwebview/webview-ct-bug

WebView versions 53 or 54 have the issue. If you update to 55 you should no longer have the issue.